# Selected item in list box keeps returning null

Tags: c#, listbox, int

i am trying to select a given number from my list box but when i run the code it returns null

i have tried .selectedvalue i have tried .selecteditem and .selecteditems
all return null

```
 ID = ExpireditemInfo.GetItemText(ExpireditemInfo.SelectedItem);
```

ID is a string

This is my source i use dapper

```
        loadinventory = iteminfo.GetExpireinfo(now,expirationDate);

        ExpirationID.DataSource = loadinventory;

        ExpirationID.DisplayMember = "Expireing_ID";
```

my data model

```
        public string Transaction_ID { get; set; }
        public string Type_Of_Transaction { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Quantity { get; set; }
        public string Unit { get; set; }

        public string Expireing_ID
        {
          get
          {
            return $"{Transaction_ID}";
          }
        }
```

i want to select the number 6 from the list-box etc and store that selection in a string which i will then convert to an int to pass along through a stored procedure. the int is for the id column of a database so it has to be an in when passing to the database.

is it that the 6 is not being recognized as a string and if so how do i select it?

Comment: Can you please post how you are filling this `listbox` and or binding to it? Depending on that, will help us further help you.

Comment: hi please see updated code

Comment: sorry if my question is dumb this is the first i am working with an int like this.

Comment: thanks for that update, now we have something. Do you set the `ValueMember`, I am not seeing that. What you should be doing is setting the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`... This way you can get the actual underlying value and not the display as they can be different.

Comment: so what i should do is get the valuemember from the list box instead ? all the numbers load to the list box i am am just not able to retrive the number from that point. or should i display member to the list box from the dapper side of this

Comment: is `loadinventory` a `DataTable` I assume? If so, can you list out the columns it returns? I will post a solution for you shortly that will help you out.

Comment: omg should transaction ID BE INT not string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i am trying to select a given number from my list box but when i run the code it returns null

After seeing the way you are binding to your `ListBox`, it seems you are not setting the `ValueMember` property, doing so you can have an actual `DisplayMember` and a `ValueMember` that represents the actual underlying value of that display object.

Here's what I would do, this is just one example:

```
 // Holds the actual selected items value
 public string ExpirationIDValue {get; private set;}

 // Anytime the selected index changes, we update our property. You can 
 // put this on the constructor and or on load.
 ExpirationID.SelectedIndexChanged += ExpirationID_SelectedIndexChanged;

 // Event handler for when selection changes
 private void ExpirationID_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (sender is ListBox listBox && listBox.SelectedValue != null)
    {
       ExpirationIDValue = listBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
    }
 }

 // This was for testing, just to get some data, you can ignore this
 DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
 dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Expireing_ID",typeof(string)));
 dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Expireing_ID_Display",typeof(string)));

 int i = 1;
 while(i < 10)
 {
    dataTable.Rows.Add(i.ToString(),$"Display {i}");
    i++;
 }

 // Here you need to make sure you set these properties to your actual
 // property names.     
 ExpirationID.DataSource = dataTable;      
 ExpirationID.DisplayMember = "Expireing_ID_Display";
 ExpirationID.ValueMember = "Expireing_ID";
```

Note: your selectedindexchanged event may fire early and cause an exception, what you can do is create a variable bool and on loading set it true and then in the event make sure that it's not true. At the end of loading the data, set that back to false.

Hopefully this will fix your issue, if there's something you don't understand or need further clarification, please let me know.

Comment: hi did you do this with an actual int i added the value member but it still retrieved null

Comment: where did you get Expireing_ID_Display?

Comment: so after a few tweak i picked a few lines from your code understood them them implemented to get my desired output. please see updated code above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help @Codexer i can finally move pass this step and i learnt a few way not to do lol

Answer (score -1):

**keycode:** public string ExpirationIDValue { get; private set; }

```
         private void ExpirationID_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {

           **keycode:** ExpirationIDValue =ExpirationID.GetItemText( 
           ExpirationID.SelectedItem);
           int ID;
           ID = Convert.ToInt32(ExpirationIDValue);

           loadinventory = iteminfo.ExpireitemInfo(ID);
           ExpireditemInfo.DataSource = loadinventory;
           ExpireditemInfo.DisplayMember = "Expireing_info";
          }
```

**Please note the valuemember was not necessary.**